# In R, chop off column after n words

Tags: r, text, nlp, data-wrangling, quanteda

I have a df with a text column, and a column with a wordcount value.

How can I delete the last n words of the text (specified in the 'wc' column) and save the output to a third column?

In other words, I need the "introductory" part of a bunch of texts, and I know when the intro ends, so I want to cut the text off at that point and save the intro in a new column.

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("this is a long text","this is also a long text", "another long text"),wc=c('1','2','1'))
```

Desired output:

| text | wc | chopped_off_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| this is a long text | 1 | this is a long |
| this is also a long text | 2 | this is also a |
| another long text | 1 | another long |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `word` function from the `stringr` package to extract "words" in a sentence. `str_count(text, "\\s") + 1` counts the number of words present in the sentence.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(chopped_off_text = 
           word(text, 1, end = str_count(text, "\\s") + 1 - as.integer(wc)))

                      text wc chopped_off_text
1      this is a long text  1   this is a long
2 this is also a long text  2   this is also a
3        another long text  1     another long
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error message: 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `chopped_off_text`.
ℹ `chopped_off_text = word(text, 1, end = str_count(text, "\\s") + 1 - as.integer(wc))`.
x argument "split" is missing, with no default

Comment: @Kasi have you tried stringr::word？I suspect you are using the word function from another package

Answer (score 2):

```r
require(quanteda)
#> Package version: 3.2.1
#> Unicode version: 13.0
#> ICU version: 69.1
#> Parallel computing: 8 of 8 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

df <- data.frame(text = c("this is a long text", 
                          "this is also a long text", 
                          "another long text"), 
                 wc = c(1, 2, 1))
corp <- corpus(df)
toks <- tokens(corp)
tokens_select(toks, startpos = rep(1, ndoc(toks)), endpos = ntoken(toks) - toks$wc)
#> Tokens consisting of 3 documents and 1 docvar.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "this" "is"   "a"    "long"
#> 
#> text2 :
#> [1] "this" "is"   "also" "a"   
#> 
#> text3 :
#> [1] "another" "long"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Seems like your result is different from OP's desired output, the words should but chopped at the end, not at the beginning

Comment: Fixed. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks so much, but how do I get the desired output in a new column in the same df, as in my desired output?

Comment: Try `stringi::stri_c_list(as.list(toks))`

Comment: that works, but the output looks like this: 'thisisalsoalongtext'

Comment: ok I did this and it sort of works: df$chopped_off_text<-as.data.frame(stringi::stri_c_list(as.list(toks),sep=' '))